# python mysql - unicode

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I have a column in mysql which is intended to take decimal values (e.g. 0.00585431)

In python, I have a function that gets this value from a webpage, then returns it into a variable. When I print this variable I get [u'0.00585431'] (which is strange)

I then try to insert this into the mysql column which is set to take a decimal(10,0) value. however, the database stores it as just a 0

the code to insert is nothing special and works for other things:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO earnings VALUES (%s)""", (variable))
```

if I change the column to a string type then it stores the whole [u'0.00585431']. So i imagine that when I try to store it as a decimal its not actually taking a proper decimal value and stores a 0 instead?

any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DECIMAL(10,0)` will give 0 to the right of the comma.

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column remains DECIMAL(M,D),
>   although the range of values for the arguments has changed somewhat:
>
> M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1
>   to 65. This introduces a possible incompatibility for older
>   applications, because previous versions of MySQL permit a range of 1
>   to 254. (The precision of 65 digits actually applies as of MySQL
>   5.0.6. From 5.0.3 to 5.0.5, the precision is 64 digits.)
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Try to change your column datatype to `DECIMAL(10,8)`

If your values will always be in same format as `0.00585431` then `DECIMAL(9,8)` would suffice.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Comment: so I made that change but it still gives me 0, along with this error:

"Warning: Incorrect decimal value: '[u'0.00585431']' for column"

Comment: I imagine it has more to do with the unicode aspect of the issue than the structure of the mysql table

Comment: You cant have [u' as decimal value. Try only integers

Comment: thats my problem. the function parses a webpage, and the return from it is exactly [u'0.00585431'] and I cant seem to cast into another type, not even str() to strip the non number characters

Comment: OK, this is a bit hacky but could work, you still have to change your decimal column type. `cur.execute("""INSERT INTO earnings VALUES (REPLACE(REPLACE(%s,'[''u',''),''']',''))""", (variable))`

Comment: Any luck with the suggestion?